How to clear cache of @connection query in Apollo
I have a query with a @Connection directive set. Now I want to clear only the cached results of this query. I can not find any examples of doing this. I tried to set the fieldName to the @Connection's key but this doesn't work.
Can this be done in Apollo?
The query:
query getEventsList ($happenedBetween: DateRangeInput, $limit: Int = 999) {
  me {
    id
    events(
        happenedBetween: $happenedBetween
        limit: $limit
    )
    @connection(key: "eventsList")
    {
        ...ShowFragment
    }
  }
}

My function to clear this query cache:
const clearCache = (): void => {
    client.cache.evict({
      id: 'ROOT_QUERY',
      fieldName: 'eventsList',
      }
    })

    client.cache.gc()
  }

